# Debugging MySQL connection issues from C# application

Tags: c#, mysql

I seem to be missing something obvious, and it's been bothering me for last few days.

I use a C# application on Windows Server 2012 to connect to MySQL database to generate a report end of the day. I use Task Scheduler to run this application.

While it seems to be running smoothly when I run manually - When the I run the application at a set time (11pm) - it throws MySQL connection error, i.e. `Unable to connect to localhost` (I email myself the error).

This has happened a few times, and I am unable to recreate the issue.

How can I troubleshoot/debug this -? I've looked into Windows Events and can't find anything. Where would MySQL connection issues be logged?

Then Connection string on App.Config

```
<add name="strConnectionString" connectionString="Database='myproject';user id='root';password='password'; Server='localhost'" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Attach the debugger when the service runs. Then set a break point on the exception.

Comment: can you post your connection string here. As some times giving an IP address in Data source is better instead of just providing the name of DataSource.

Comment: are you launching it as well from your machine in the Task Scheduler..? if not then you need to change the connection strings datasource from localhost to the actual name of the database also take a look at this link 
[C# Connection Strings](http://www.connectionstrings.com) and go to the section for `MySql`

Comment: Are you sure you're connecting to the DBMS on the correct port? Verify that you're listening/connecting on the default port.

Comment: @MethodMan, it works smoothly on most times on TaskScheduler - except when I want it at .

Comment: @PatrickHofman - Can you explain more on that? My application is an installable one.

Comment: @mjw Yes, its on correct port.

Comment: all I will try again tonight with 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost. I am also enclosing it with a timer, and loggers, to see if it reconnects after a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Changed "localhost" to 127.0.0.1 in the connection string seems to have done the trick. I don't know why however.